# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Can't Parse (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am getting the following error when I am trying to parse "bloomberg" out of the self.web_url. type of self.web_url is unicode, so I am assuming that might be the reason why. However, I do not know how to implement type conversions if necessary or what to do

```
self.web_url = "http://www.bloomberg.com"
start = "http:/www."
    end = ".com")
    print type(self.web_url)
    web_name = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), self.web_url).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because there is no match. Your pattern is incorrect since it matches a single `/`, while there are 2 `/`s after `http:`. You need to fix the pattern as heemayl suggests or use an alternative `urlparse` based solution to get the `netloc` part, and get the part in between the first and last dots (either with `find` and `rfind`, or regex):

```
import urlparse, re
path = urlparse.urlparse("http://www.bloomberg.com")
print(path.netloc[path.netloc.find(".")+1:path.netloc.rfind(".")]) # => bloomberg
# or a regex:
print(re.sub(r"\A[^.]*\.(.*)\.[^.]*\Z", r"\1", path.netloc)) # => bloomberg
# or Regex 2:
mObj = re.search(r"\.(.*)\.", path.netloc);
if mObj:
    print(mObj.group(1)) # => bloomberg
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/lcitI2)

Regex 1 - `\A[^.]*\.(.*)\.[^.]*\Z` - will  will match the start of string (`\A`), then 0+ non-`.`s (`[^.]*`), then a dot (`\.`), then will capture any 0+ chars other than a newline into Group 1, then will match `.` and 0+ non-`.`s up to the very end of the string (`\Z`).

Regex 2 will just match the first `.` followed with any 0+ chars up to the last `.` capturing what is in between `.`s into Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `/` in `start`:

```
start = 'http://www.'
```

Also note that, the `.` has a special meaning in Regex, its a Regex token that will match any single character, not literal `.`. You need to escape it to make it literal i.e. `\.`.

So you better do:

```
start = "http://www\."
end = "\.com"
```

Comment: And what about a dot?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Which one?